# Ошибка при работе aiogram с postgresql

Tags: python, postgresql, aiogram, asyncpg

Я разрабатываю бота на aiogram. Очевидно, что для создания базы данных лучше подойдет ассихронная СУБД.Поэтому я выбрал оболочку для postgresql - asyncpg.

Вот код для бд, в котором я написал функцию для добавления ton-кошельков пользователей:

```py
import asyncpg

user = '',
password = '',
database = '',
host = 'localhost'


async def add_wallets(wallet):
    conn = await asyncpg.connect(user=user, password=password, database=database, host=host)
    await conn.execute("""INSERT INTO users(wallet) VALUES($1,)""", wallet)
    await conn.close()
```

Эту функцию я импортировал в свой основной код. Вот код обработчика, который принимает данные от пользователя:

```py
@dp.message_handler(state=AddTon.wallet)
async def add_ton(message: types.Message, state=FSMContext):
    wallet = str('wallet')
    await new_ton.add_wallets(wallet)
    await state.finish()
    await message.answer('Ваш ton кошелёк был добавлен')
```

Как только пользователь вводит данные, появляется ошибка:

```
  File "asyncpg\protocol\protocol.pyx", line 956, in asyncpg.protocol.protocol.BaseProtocol.connection_made
AttributeError: 'Protocol' object has no attribute '_on_error'
```

Очень надеюсь на вашу помощь, так как уже достаточно намучался с этой проблемой. За раннее спасибо.
Если вам ещё потребуется код, то я его скину.

Comment: Судя по всему, по каким-то причинам дропается коннект. Попробуйте к БД подключиться через PgAdmin или через пайчарм; ну и используйте пул соединений

Comment: @ClarkDevlin, спасибо, я попробую пул. Что касается PgAdmin: я пытался подключиться, всё работает без проблем. Pycharm: весь мой код на нем и написан и именно в его терминал выводится ошибка

Comment: @ClarkDevlin, сейчас появилась возможность создать пул, но должный эффект так и не произошел